# data mismatch in array's C# when both are made equal

Tags: c#, .net

I declared an array like

```
string[] arr1;
string[] arr2;
```

In one point i assigend value for that

```
arr1 = new string[] { "value1" , "Value2 };
arr2 = arr1;
```

After that again i am changing that value of arr1 like

```
arr1[0]="value3";
arr1[1]="value4";
```

now if i check the arr2 these changes in arr1 also reflects.

```
arr2[0] value is "value3";
arr2[1] value is "value4";
```

how its happening ?

Comment: fair! arr2 is just a reference of arr1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrays are reference types in .NET. When you did `arr2 = arr1` you made both variables point to the same array in memory. Any change to the elements of one will be directly reflected in the other.

To make a copy of an array, use the [`Array.Clone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clone.aspx) method:

```
arr2 = (string[])arr1.Clone();
```

or Linq's [`Enumerable.ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) method:

```
arr2 = arr1.ToArray();
```

Comment: so all changes in arr1 reflect arr2 without changing arr2.
same if changed arr2 it will reflect arr1 right ?

Answer (score 1):

because `arr2` is reference to `arr1` so `arr2` is point to `arr1` in memory. every change to `arr1` will reflect to `arr2`.